# Format jsp with jstl tags in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jstl

I want to make sure the jstl and spring tags are on their own line. There is an "inline elements" in the Formatting in the Editor, but it wont let me insert a tag with a ":" in it.
Any suggestions